# can't connect to webserver through arduino

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I've the following problem and I just can't figure out how to fix it. I'm currently working on a prototype for my thesis. For this prototype I need my Arduino to connect to the internet. I've a Arduino Uno and a Arduino Ethernet Shield.

The problem is that I can't connect to the webserver of my company where I'm currently following a internship.

The webserver has a different IP then the LAN that I'm working on. When I'm typing in my command window ipconfig /all I get the following information:

**MAC address:** 64-31-50-25-FE-C7

**IPv4-address:** 10.100.5.144

**subnet mask:** 255.255.248.0

**gateway:** 10.100.0.1

The IP address where the webserver is installed is: 10.100.0.40.

When I'm requesting a page with GET and I want to get the file index.html who is stored in my www folder of the webserver (see below), I get the 404 error.

\efocus02\www\evs\navid\navid.mirzaie.milani\webroot

This is the URL that I request: http://navid.mirzaie.milani.navid.efocus02.efocus.local/test.html

Is there someone who can help me how I can figure this issue, I would really, really appreciate it.

Comment: You say you need the _index.html_, but the request URL is for a _test.html_. Also, did you try accessing the server by IP, like: http://10.100.0.40/index.html ?

Comment: @DimKo on ip 10.100.0.40 they installed a drupal, so when i'm requesting that IP i'm getting HTML output of the index.html, but i want to acces my folder and get the info of test.htm.

Comment: You are on the incorrect IP range. The webserver is on 10.100.0.40 and your arduino is 10.100. **5** .144 . There is no route to the device. If you got internet request it from the internet instead rather than internally

Comment: Not an electronics question. Probably will be closed.

Answer (score 5):

As you are getting a 404 error, the Arduino must be correctly connected to the network and able to access the web server.

(My best guess, given limited information, is that the web server is using Virtual Hosting and your Arduino is not sending a "Host:" HTTP header).

In order to debug the problem, you need to see what's going on at the network level.
Either, add debugging to your Arduino HTTP library or sniff the network with a PC.

I'd recommend using a PC. Use an ethernet hub (not a switch), or connection share the Arduino through a PC then run [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to sniff the network packets. Check that the Arduino really is requesting the page you think it is. Check the response codes coming back.

Recreate the HTTP request on a PC, send exactly the same data - do you get the same 404 response? You can do this with telnet or with a more powerful tool like curl or wget.

Comment: Jeffrey, the main problem is that i can't connect to the webserver and i don't know how to accomplished that and i'm really getting a headache as i busy with this issue for many hours.

Comment: You don't need to access the web server or sniff the traffic. You can install on a normal PC on the LAN a web server (XAMPP, to name one), and set arduino to get the page from that PC. You'll see on the log what arduino is really asking. I agree with Toby's best guess: missing host http header.

Comment: @Axeman i just installed wamp on my PC and its default on ip : 127.0.0.1 when i'm connecting to this IP through a example code i can't see anything when i'm requesting 127.0.0.1 in my browser.

Comment: I wrote a blog along these lines  a while back: http://blog.wickeddevice.com/?p=245

Comment: Forget the Arduino. Just get a Raspberry Pi - What is your thesis about- ripping out hair from stress?

Comment: @vicatcu i already fixed this issue, but not from the webserver side it gave me headache. What i did was i just bought a VPS from a hosting provider, and i've now 1 ip available and now i can connect to that vps and do whatever i want.